# Find equation of curve equidistant from two ellipses

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

For visualizing some geometric curve, I have to choose a way between finding sampling points on the curve by numerical processing and finding curve equation of that curve.

The curve that I want to visualize is equidistant from two different ellipses.

Each length of major axis, minor axis, and the angle between x-axis and major axis of two ellipse is given.

I think there can be two inflection points on the curve.
What is the equation of that curve?

[image: BlueCurve]

The blue curve on upper image is the result from numerical processing.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you come up with an expression for the distance of a point to an ellipse?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried? Can you handle the special case of two circles?

Comment: @amd I realized that I need first is the expression for the distance of a point to boundary of an ellipse. I now use that method to calculate distance. I move and rotate a given ellipse to make an ellipse which is centered at the origin and not rotated. After then, I calculate the distance from the point also transformed.

Comment: Did you see [THIS](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26324-distance-between-points-and-ellipse?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)?

Comment: Are your ellipses always non-intersecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in general a difficult calculation.

> Farouki, Rida T., and John K. Johnstone. "Computing point/curve and curve/curve bisectors." *IMA Conference on the Mathematics of Surfaces*. 1992.
>   ([PDF download](https://info.cs.uab.edu/jj/papers/swept/curveBisectorMOS.pdf).)
>
> ---
>
> [image: Bisector]

---

> Ramamurthy, Rajesh, and Rida T. Farouki. "Voronoi diagram and medial axis algorithm for planar domains with curved boundaries I. Theoretical foundations." *Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics* 102.1 (1999): 119-141.

See also this Inst. Math & Appl website, [Voronoi Diagram of Ellipses](https://www.ima.umn.edu/impacts/voronoi):

---

[image: VDsite]

---

Comment: I imagine a Voronoi diagram of a bunch of ellipses can look messy for sufficiently perverse configurations.

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: Yes indeed! See the IMA website I just linked.

Comment: "...reduced this query to calculations on algebraic numbers of degree 184." - I'm now slightly afraid to look at the algorithm at this point. :D

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician: Degree 184---Wow!.

Comment: Actually, the curve what I want to know eqution of is an edge of Voronoi diagram. I thought the degree might be 3 but....TT.